# List school name in more than 2 states based on student loan

Tags: sql, sql-server

tbl1: schID, SChName

tbl2: SchID, stuid, city, state, loan_purpose, Action

I have two tables, tbl1 lists school ids and school names, and tbl2 lists studentid, loan purpose and action taken by school.
I need help with writing a query to list school names that accepted 
applications in more than 2 states (when loan type = "FS" and action is "A).

Comment: For reference, people are generally happy to help, but be sure to do more research and what you've tried so far. -http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select SCHName FROM(
    select tbl1.schname, count(*) FROM 
 tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.SCHID = tbl2.SCHID 
 WHERE tbl2.loan_purpose = 'FS' AND tbl2.ACTION = 'A'
 GROUP BY SCHName
HAVING count(*) > 2
                    )
```

Comment: Doesn't meet business rules if school has 2 records in tbl2 for same state (different cities).

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right if thats the way his homework database is designed; I'd go with yours since it accounts for that.

Comment: how you go about schools with 2 records in tbl2 for same state (different cities)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a `GROUP BY` using the `WHERE` to apply your row-level filters (action and loan purpose), and then `HAVING` for the aggregation filter (state count).

```
SELECT
    tbl1.SchID,
    tbl1.SchName
FROM tbl1
    INNER JOIN tbl2
        ON tbl1.SchID = tbl2.SchID
WHERE tbl2.loan_purpose = 'FS'
    AND tbl2.Action = 'A'
GROUP BY
    tbl1.SchID,
    tbl1.SchName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tbl2.state) > 2
ORDER BY
    tbl1.SchName
```

Comment: @user3267270 - If this answer solved problem then you need to mark it as answer by selecting the **tick mark** to the left of this answer.